# custom wordpress post type hierarchical alternative

Tags: php, wordpress

I have inherited a wordpress project that uses a custom post type 'project'

```
$args = array(
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Projekte' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Projekt' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Neues Projekt erstellen' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Neues Projekt erstellen' ),
        'edit' => __( 'Bearbeiten' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Projekt bearbeiten' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'Neues Projekt anlegen' ),
        'view' => __( 'Projekt anzeigen' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'Projekt anzeigen' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Projekt suchen' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Kein Projekt gefunden' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Kein Projekt im Papierkorb' ),
        'parent' => __( 'Übergeordnetes Projekt' ),
    ),
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'page-attributes',
        'thumbnail'
    ),
    'capability_type' => 'project',
    'capabilities' => array(
        'publish_posts' => 'publish_projects',
        'edit_posts' => 'edit_projects',
        'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_projects',
        'delete_posts' => 'delete_projects',
        'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_projects',
        'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_projects',
        'edit_post' => 'edit_project',
        'delete_post' => 'delete_project',
        'read_post' => 'read_project',
        'create_posts' => 'create_projects',
    ),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-analytics'
);
register_post_type( 'project', $args );
```

The hierarchical is set to true, the result being in the admin the user can clearly see which post is a child of what. The wordpress installation has many users that can all manage the content of their own respective projects.

There are approx 3000 projects in the system at present.

There is now a problem when logging into the wp-admin and loading the projects page:

- When the last page is loaded, the load time is over 1 1/2 minutes.
- The definition of the "last page" in this instance is when the user clicks on the last page in the pagination links, or, if the user can only see one page of projects.

I have found that this load time issue can be improved by turning off `hierarchical`. However this then renders a flat view of projects which is not what the customer needs...

It seems i am stuck between a rock and hard place. Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a resolution?

EDIT:
Additional info:

- All plugins have been turned off but the page still loaded very slowly.
- The dev env is on a server with ample RAM and CPU.
- The front end is running fine.

This is the mysql slow log that traced all mysql queries from the start to the end of the slow wp-admin page load:

```
    # User@Host: wp_user[wp_user] @ localhost []  Id:    50
# Query_time: 0.004904  Lock_time: 0.000116 Rows_sent: 403  Rows_examined: 578
SET timestamp=1467216512;
SELECT option_name, option_value FROM options WHERE autoload = 'yes';
# Time: 2016-06-29T16:08:32.265525Z
# User@Host: wp_user[wp_user] @ localhost []  Id:    50
# Query_time: 0.000267  Lock_time: 0.000110 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 47
SET timestamp=1467216512;
SELECT COUNT(*)
                                                        FROM icl_translation_status
                                                        WHERE translation_service = 'icanlocalize';
# Time: 2016-06-29T16:08:32.331843Z
# User@Host: wp_user[wp_user] @ localhost []  Id:    50
# Query_time: 0.000760  Lock_time: 0.000117 Rows_sent: 105  Rows_examined: 212
SET timestamp=1467216512;
SELECT
                                                st.value AS tra,
                                                s.value AS org,
                                                s.domain_name_context_md5 AS ctx
                                        FROM icl_strings s
                                        LEFT JOIN icl_string_translations st
                                                ON s.id=st.string_id
AND st.status=10
AND st.language='de'
AND s.language!='de';
# Time: 2016-06-29T16:08:32.530835Z
# User@Host: wp_user[wp_user] @ localhost []  Id:    50
# Query_time: 0.000215  Lock_time: 0.000098 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 14
SET timestamp=1467216512;
SELECT t.element_id, tax.term_id, tax.taxonomy
                                                                                                        FROM icl_translations t
                                JOIN term_taxonomy tax
                                        ON t.element_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id
AND t.element_type = CONCAT('tax_', tax.taxonomy)
                                                                                                        JOIN terms terms
                                                                                                         ON terms.term_id = tax.term_id
                                                                                                        WHERE tax.term_id != tax.term_taxonomy_id;
# Time: 2016-06-29T16:08:32.562377Z
# User@Host: wp_user[wp_user] @ localhost []  Id:    50
# Query_time: 0.000298  Lock_time: 0.000116 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 47
SET timestamp=1467216512;
SELECT COUNT(*)
                                                        FROM icl_translation_status
                                                        WHERE translation_service = 'icanlocalize';
# Time: 2016-06-29T16:08:32.770419Z
# User@Host: wp_user[wp_user] @ localhost []  Id:    50
# Query_time: 0.001579  Lock_time: 0.000607 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 21
SET timestamp=1467216512;
SELECT  comment_approved, COUNT( * ) AS num_comments FROM comments   JOIN icl_translations icltr2
                                                        ON icltr2.element_id = comments.comment_post_ID
                                                        JOIN posts ON  posts.ID = icltr2.element_id
AND CONCAT('post_', posts.post_type) = icltr2.element_type
                                                LEFT JOIN icl_translations icltr_comment
                                                        ON icltr_comment.element_id = comments.comment_ID
AND icltr_comment.element_type = 'comment'
                                         WHERE 1=1   AND (  ( posts.post_type = 'attachment' AND ( ( ( posts.post_type = 'attachment' AND ( posts.post_author = 181 OR ( posts.post_parent = 0  ) OR ( posts.post_parent > 0  ) ) ) )  ) )  OR  ( posts.post_type = 'project' AND ( ( ( 1=1 AND (  (  ( posts.post_author = 181 ) AND posts.post_status IN ('publish','future','draft','pending','private','inherit') )  ) ) OR (  (  ( posts.ID IN ('8132','8133','8134','8141','8142','8143','8144','8145','8146','8147','8148','8149','8150','8151','8152','8140','8135') )  )  ) )  ) )  OR  ( posts.post_type = 'event' AND ( ( 1=1 AND (  (  ( posts.post_author = 181 ) AND posts.post_status IN ('publish','future','draft','pending','private','inherit') )  ) )  ) )  ) AND ( ( comment_approved = '0' OR comment_approved = '1' ) )  AND icltr2.language_code = 'de'
AND (icltr_comment.language_code IS NULL
OR icltr_comment.language_code = icltr2.language_code
                                                                                                       )  GROUP BY comment_approved  ORDER BY comments.comment_date_gmt DESC;
# Time: 2016-06-29T16:08:32.786531Z
# User@Host: wp_user[wp_user] @ localhost []  Id:    50
# Query_time: 0.003861  Lock_time: 0.000051 Rows_sent: 403  Rows_examined: 578
SET timestamp=1467216512;
SELECT option_name, option_value FROM options WHERE autoload = 'yes';
```

This is a snapshot of the projects page that loads perfectly fine, till you reach the last page in the pagination... and the result is it takes forever to load.
[image: This is a snapshot of the projects page that loads perfectly fine, till you reach the last page in the pagination... and the result is it takes forever to load.]

Comment: 3000 posts are not a lot, disable all plugins and check again. By the way it could be the hosting.

Comment: I tried disabling all plugins and the issue didn't change. The clients prod server is a lower spec than our dev server. On our dev server the load time with hierarchical = 1min 30sec. On the clients prod server the page doesn't actually load.

Comment: Try running a query in phpmyadmin `SELECT ID, post_title FROM posts WHERE post_type="project" LIMIT 15, 10` and see how fast is running also check the total count of `project` posts in case you have revisions bloating the database.

Comment: @Ervald  I narrowed it down to not being a mysql issue. The query you suggested returned with issue `Showing rows 15 - 24 (10 total, Query took 0.0473 sec)`. I ran a mysql slow log against the page in question and posted the full log in the OP above.

Comment: Do you have any extra filters running in the admin page for projects? Like custom columns etc

Comment: Nothing special. I uploaded a screenshot of the projects page as seen by the admin. The only answers i can find else where is to turn off the hierarchical.. but as you can see this would render the admin view kinda useless.